# Ubuntu 20.04 mouse issues

Tags: mouse, 20.04

Ive spent the last hour looking things up only to not have much success maybe it's just me. Not sure. I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 on my laptop. Lenovo thinkpad, Now it seems when i walk away from it and let it suspend the mouse seems to be frozen in place, it absolutely will not respond. I have restart the whole system for it to work again.

Comment: Does this also happen when you suspend manually?

Comment: Only when it times out by itself.